# Parsing JSON in java - how to get String or JsonObject from json file property(value - json object) using POJO only

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

The json structure is the following:

```
{
  "key":"Key",
  "value":{
  "first": "first",
  "second": "second"
  }
}
```

I want using ***Spring Boot*** get this json as ***Plain Old Java Object***.

```
public class File {
    private String key;
    private JsonObject value;

    public File(String key, JsonObject value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public File() {
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public JsonObject getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(JsonObject value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

***JsonObject*** - the class from ***lib com.google.gson***
I am getting **{}**

It would be perfect to get field "value" as ***String*** but ***JsonObject*** is okay too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! It's possible with com.google.json lib using setter:

```
public class File {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public File() {
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = new Gson().toJson(value);
    }
}
```